# How can I access my class instance from a boost thread?

Tags: c++, boost, multithreading

I have the following code (this is some semi-sudo code, which may not compile):

```
class FooBar {
public:
    void a();
    void b();
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> m_thread;
    std::string m_test;
};

void FooBar::a() {
    m_test = "Foo bar"
    m_thread = shared_ptr<thread>(new thread(bind(&FooBar::b, this)));
}

void FooBar::b() {
    cout << m_test;
}
```

The code `cout << test` does not yield any output, because `m_test` is `""` instead of `"Foo bar"`. Why is this? I thought that passing `this` as the 2nd argument to `bind` would allow me to access the same instance from `b()` - am I incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that works.  Here's the "real" version, which does in fact print "Foo bar":

```
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace boost;

struct FooBar {
    void a();
    void b();
    shared_ptr<thread> m_thread;
    std::string m_test;
};

void FooBar::a() {
    m_test = "Foo bar";
    m_thread = make_shared<thread>(bind(&FooBar::b, this));
}

void FooBar::b() {
    std::cout << m_test;
}

int main() {
    FooBar fb;
    fb.a();
    fb.m_thread->join();
    return 0;
}
```

> The code `cout << test` does not yield any output, because `m_test` is ""

I suspect this is because the object was being destroyed before the thread got around to evaluating the member variable.  Note the `join()`, it's very important.

Comment: Excellent thanks for posting working code! And yes, I put a breakpoint in the destructor and hey presto, turns out I was using a full type for my static singleton, instead of a pointer - duh! So a new instance was being created every time I called the singleton. Fixed now, thanks again for your code.